# Bit of confusion regarding a functor?

Tags: haskell

Im trying to understand what a functor is, i found this tutorial/example:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Solutions/Applicative_Functors

```
 data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

The functor for the above type being:

```
 instance Functor Tree where
   fmap f (Node a ts) = Node (f a) (map (fmap f) ts)
```

could someone help explain what exactly they have done and why they have done it? My understanding is that a functor allows you to iterate over a data type. I cant seem to understand the syntax used though?

Comment: Another good place to learn about functors is the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/e/e9/Typeclassopedia.pdf). Which part of the syntax is giving you trouble in particular?

Comment: @user997112 `ts` is bound to the value of the second field of `Node` which is of type `[Tree a]`, so `ts` is the subtree held by that node.

Comment: @user997112 Adding to what @ionu said, Haskell uses pattern matching in function definitions on the left-hand side of the equals sign. `fmap f (Node a ts)` binds `a` and `ts` to the first and second parts of `Node` respectively. It's common for Haskell programmers to give lists plural names. The name `ts` hints that it is a "list of trees".

Comment: @Michael, the only bit i dont get is the (fmap f) part?

Comment: @user997112 You know that `map` applies some function to every element of a list. The `fmap` function is like that, except that how it works depends on the type it is applied to. In this case `map (fmap f) ts` is applying `fmap f` to every element in a list of `Tree a` elements. `fmap f` will be recursively applied all the way down the tree structure. Eventually there will likely be a `Node <something> []`, and then the recursion will stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Functor` is useful for mapping between two data representations. Sometimes that might resemble iteration, sometimes not. Having this common `Functor` typeclass allows us to ignore the actual structure of the data type (`Maybe`, `List`, `Tree`) and focus only on the data they contain. The author of that data type should know how that data structure might be traversed/iterated so he should provide the implementation for that (in the form of a `Functor` instance of that data type). All we have to provide is that function `f` which takes an `a` and maps it to a `b`. For example:

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
  deriving Show

instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Node a ts) = Node (f a) (map (fmap f) ts)

main :: IO ()
main = do print (toLower `fmap` (Node 'F' [])) -- Node 'f' []
          print (toLower `fmap` (Just 'F'))    -- Just 'f'
          print (toLower `fmap` "FOO")         -- "foo"
```

We were able to lowercase those chars using the same code `toLower` combined with `fmap`.

So, what you should do when defining that `Functor` instance is to extract inner data using pattern matching, and the apply the received callback function `f` to each of these results.

An infix synonym for `fmap` can be found in the `Control.Applicative` module, called [`<$>`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a%3C%24%3E).

```
main :: IO ()
main = do print (toLower <$> (Node 'F' [])) -- Node 'f' []
          print (toLower <$> (Just 'F'))    -- Just 'f'
          print (toLower <$> "FOO")         -- "foo"
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen Haskell before in my life, but I'm guessing that it's defining a data type (called Tree) that consists of a Node that contains a value, and an array of Trees (which would be the branches of the original tree). It then defines a function that operates on a function and a tree, and creates a new tree by applying the function to the Node's value, and applying itself recursively to all the branches in the array (using the map function as a shortcut).

Comment: If you have never see. Haskell before that was very well done.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, in Haskell, you can think of a functor as:

1. a box that contains a value in a special context (IO, Maybe, Either a)
2. a structure that holds multiple values (Tree, Map a, List)

Additionally, a functor has an operation -- `fmap` -- that understands its specific structure.

Using `fmap`, you can easily apply a structure-preserving transformation to a functor. For example, `fmap (+ 1)` is a function that adds 1 to any functor:

```
Prelude> fmap (+ 1) [1,2 ] -- using a list functor
[2,3]
Prelude> fmap (+ 1) (Just 2) -- using a maybe functor
Just 3
```

In the example you've given, `Tree` is given a Functor instance -- an implementation of `fmap` -- that understands the structure of a tree, and abstracts that away for you.

A great resource for Functors, Applicative Functors, Monads, Monoids is [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: So is it basically defining 'map' for a custom data type?

Comment: @user997112 -- that's a good way of looking at it.  `fmap` is a generalization of `map`.